# C++ if statement giving incorrect output

Tags: c++, logic

The code compares the difference of two numbers(total and candidate) and sees if that difference is smaller or equal than 3. As you can see in the result below. Some number's with differences below 3 are printed and there are those that have a difference over 3 and are still printed.

```
if ((candidate - total) <= 3) {
    cout << candidate << endl;
    cout << "total - candidate = " << total - candidate << endl;
}
```

It returns :

```
30
total - candidate = 12
32
total - candidate = -1
36
total - candidate = 13
40
total - candidate = 10
42
total - candidate = 12
48
total - candidate = 28
54
total - candidate = 12
```

What is causing the problem here?

Comment: `candidate - total` is not equal `total - candidate`. Also, please don't post images of code, copy and paste it here.

Comment: Are you using threads ? This may cause the value to be changed between the moment it's instantiated and printed

Comment: are u using signed or unsigned int?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen if `candidate - total <= 3` then `total - candidate` shouldn't be `-1`. That's not where the issue is

Comment: @Hearner `candidate` is equal 32 in the case you mentioned. Let's say `total` is 31. `candidate - total` is 1, which is less than 3. `total - candidate` is -1.

Comment: id10T error! (`candidate-total`  not the same as `total-candidate`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to see the variables on which you had put the conditions.
Firstly, you are checking condition for candidate-total, put printing total-candidate.
They are not equal

Answer (score 0):

Output is correct. Your if condition is wrong. It should be like this -

```
if ((total - candidate) <= 3) {
    cout << candidate << endl;
    cout << "total - candidate = " << total - candidate << endl;
}
```